# Who Collected all the stones before thanos did?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok* an infinity gauntlet was visible, does this mean Odin had it in the first place? Was he the one who put the stones in different realms?

Comment: I dont think linked question has answer to OP's question written in title

Comment: If you follow up with the movie more carefully, you can see that it has mentioned Odin didn't had the Gauntlet, the one showed in the Odin's was actually a fake. And at the first part in Infinity war, Wong explained how infinity stones comes to reality and how they spread throughout the universe

Comment: @ZaidSyedMMd actually it is..